# unable to display png and gives warning in some part of code in my application after msi installation

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-installer, visual-c++-2008, vc90

I want to know the complete method of `msi installation` because The msi file created when installed is not displaying the pictures that are of `.png` type why does this happen and how to solve this problem?

Before creating msi when I execute the program in the `vc++2008` it is showing pictures. why I am not able to view png pictures, when I create the same program msi and other pics of `bitmap type` can be viewed.

I have placed png pictures in res folder, and  followed the following procedure
**`solution explorer->ResourceFiles->right click mouse->add existing item->(added png files of res folder)`**

What else should I do to make my png pictures appear after installing msi.
I have used `picture ctrl to display png`.

Answer (score 1):

The msi instaler (`msiexec`) does not work with `png` images. You can only use `bmp` and `jpg` images.

See the docs about the image properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kbk77sf.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4dddtk.aspx